# Print methods in Roxygen2

Tags: r, roxygen2

I am trying to get familiar with the package `roxygen2`.
In particular, I want to understand how print summary methods work in `roxygen2`.
Suppose that I need to create a function of the kind:

```
#' my function
#' @param mat an object of class \code{matrix} with 4 rows and 4 columns
#' @return an object of class \code{matrix} with 4 rows and 4 columns
#' @export
my_function <- function(mat){
  res <- list()
  res[["output.1"]] <- mat
  class(res) <- "mynewpackage"
  attributes(res[["output.1"]])$attr <- "output.a"
  res[["output.2"]] <- mat
  class(res) <- "mynewpackage"
  attributes(res[["output.2"]])$attr <- "output.a"
  res[["output.3"]] <- mat
  class(res) <- "mynewpackage"
  attributes(res[["output.3"]])$attr <- "output.b"
  return(res)
}
```

Then I want to create a `summary` for my function. I do:

```
#' summary
#' @title summary
#' @method summary mynewpackage
#' @noRd
#' @export
"summary.mynewpackage" <- function(object, print = "output.1", ...) {

  if (print == "output.1") {
    res <- list(coefficients = object[["output.1"]],
                print = print)
    print(res)
  } else if (print == "output.2") {
    res <- list(coefficients = object[["output.2"]],
                print = print)
    print(res)
  } else if (print == "output.3") {
    res <- list(coefficients = object[["output.3"]],
                print = print)
    print(res)
  }

  class(res) <- "summary.mynewpackage"
  res
}
```

Finally, I want my the output of my summary to look more like`print.summary.lm`. 
To this purpose, and this is where I get lost, I tried, unsuccesfully, something like:

```
#' print
#' @title print
#' @aliases print.mynewpackage
#' @param x numeric number
#' @param digits number of digits
#' @param ... other arguments
#' @noRd
#' @export
"print.mynewpackage" <- function(x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), ...) {

  x <- x[[sample(1:3, 1)]]

  if( attributes(x[["output.1"]])$attr == "output.a" ) {

    print.default(format(x[,1], digits = digits), print.gap = 2L,
                  quote = FALSE)
    cat("\n")
    invisible(x)
  } else {

    print.default(format(x[,1], digits = digits), print.gap = 2L,
    quote = FALSE)
    cat("\n")
    invisible(x)
  }

}
#' @rdname print
#' @param x numeric number
#' @param ... other arguments
#' @method print summary
#' @noRd
#' @export
"print.summary" <- function(x, ...){
  UseMethod("print.summary")
}
#' @rdname print
#' @title print
#' @name print
#' @aliases print.summary
#' @param object numeric number
#' @param ... additional parameters
#' @param print object to be printed
#' @param digits number of digits to be printed
#' @param signif.stars TRUE or FALSE
#' @method print.summary mynewpackage
#' @importFrom stats printCoefmat
#' @export
"print.summary.mynewpackage" <- function(object, print = "output.1", digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), signif.stars = getOption("show.signif.stars"), ...) {

  if (print == "output.1") {
    printCoefmat(object[["output.1"]], digits = digits, signif.stars = signif.stars)
  } else if (print == "output.2") {
    printCoefmat(object[["output.2"]], digits = digits, signif.stars = signif.stars)
  } else if (print == "output.3") {
    printCoefmat(object[["output.3"]], digits = digits, signif.stars = signif.stars)
  }
}
```

What I was expecting was to run

```
cmat <- cbind(rnorm(3, 10), sqrt(rchisq(3, 12)))
cmat <- cbind(cmat, cmat[, 1]/cmat[, 2])
cmat <- cbind(cmat, 2*pnorm(-cmat[, 3]))
colnames(cmat) <- c("Estimate", "Std.Err", "Z value", "Pr(>z)")

my_function(cmat)
summary(my_function(cmat))
```

And obtain for `summary(my_function(cmat))` the output produced by `print.summary.mynewpackage(my_function(cmat))`

However, the only way to access to `print.summary.mynewpackage()` is to run:

```
mynewpackage:::print.my_new_function(my_function(cmat))
```

Any hint on how should I do this?